# How to get the attribute in react without component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

How to get the attribute `data-digit` and the class `gauge, gauge-outer, gauge-inner and gauge-digits`

***TSX***

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './gauge.module.scss';


const Gauge = (props) => {
    const points = 43;
    const radius = 257;
    const max = 100;
    const peaks = [10, 50, 90];
    const step = (max + 1) / points;
    const realPeaks = peaks.map(peak => Math.floor(peak * (1 / step)));
    const hueStep = 120 / points;

    return (
        <>
            <div className={style['gauge']} data-digit={50}>       
                <div className={style['gauge-outer']}></div>
                <div className={style['gauge-inner']}></div>
                <div className={style['gauge-digits']}></div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default Gauge;
```

I added this code below the const hueStep.

```
 const gaugeDigits = document.getElementsByClassName('gauge-digits');
    console.log(gaugeDigits)
```

But it doesn't work, the error: document is undefined

Comment: Is this something you are doing for debugging purposes, or in your source code?  95% of the time if you're doing direct DOM interrogation/manipulation in React you're doing something wrong and using an antipattern.  Also, it is unclear the context in which this is happening; could you create a [mcve] as a snippet in your question?

Comment: Dont directly access the DOM (not the React way of doing it). In your case use `useState` eg: `const [digits, setDigits] = useState(50);` and  use like `<div className={style['gauge']} data-digit={digits}>`

Comment: How'bout, how to get the attribute of className ```gauge```? also the attribute data-digits? @kiranvj

Comment: Where exactly do you want to get the attributes and on what conditions? If you can update your use case you may get more solutions on how to do it. Either way accessing DOM directly will not get the desired results as React uses virtual DOM. Any regarding your error `document is undefined`  try `window.document....`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` to access the DOM after it is rendered:

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const gaugeDigits = document.getElementsByClassName('gauge-digits');
    console.log(gaugeDigits)
}, [])
```

Probably better would be to also use `useRef`:

```
const Gauge = (props) => {
    const ref = useRef( null );

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log( 'ref.current:', ref.current );
    }, [])

    return (<>
        <div className={style['gauge']} data-digit={50} ref={ ref } >
            <div className={style['gauge-outer']}></div>
            <div className={style['gauge-inner']}></div>
            <div className={style['gauge-digits']}></div>
        </div>
    </>);
};
```

**Note:**
usually you should not need to access the DOM. Your program should work with state, and then let React render the DOM according to this state.